# How to create a new column that gets an expanding day difference in date column?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, numpy

How do I create a new column that gets rolling or expanding date (day) difference?

For example, df should look like this

```
Date          DayDifference 
2014-01-01     0
2014-01-02     1 
2014-01-04     2
2014-01-08     4
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply:

```
df["Day Difference"] = df.Date.diff().dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

output:

```
        Date  Day Difference
0 2014-01-01               0
1 2014-01-02               1
2 2014-01-04               2
3 2014-01-08               4
```

Comment: and I think you can do `df.Date.diff().dt.days` to just get the `int`.